# Google Maps plugin crashes Flutter app when displayed

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

Whenever I try to display a google maps widget my app crashes, the reason given in the logs is:

```
W/com.foody.food( 6310): Unsupported class loader
W/com.foody.food( 6310): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule( 6310): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
I/DynamiteModule( 6310): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
V/DynamiteModule( 6310): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/com.foody.food( 6310): Unsupported class loader
I/Google Maps Android API( 6310): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API( 6310): Google Play services package version: 15090039
I/DpmTcmClient( 6310): RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
E/GoogleMapController( 6310): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310): Process: com.foody.foody, PID: 6310
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at fb.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@15090083@15.0.90 (100408-231259764):3)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at fa.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@15090083@15.0.90 (100408-231259764):3)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at fc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@15090083@15.0.90 (100408-231259764):15)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.al.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@15090083@15.0.90 (100408-231259764):6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at ee.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@15090083@15.0.90 (100408-231259764):23)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at ee.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@15090083@15.0.90 (100408-231259764):8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000035/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000035/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@15090083@15.0.90 (100408-231259764):4)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6310):    ... 6 more
I/Process ( 6310): Sending signal. PID: 6310 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

My AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foody.foody">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="foody"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBM8ywYw1UDb3aXaTF3w21EJ86ePWmAkPE"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And I try to display the map like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'reservation.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'feed.dart';


class info extends StatelessWidget {
  info([this.id]);

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  int id;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Reservation(id)),
          );
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        label: Text('Book a Table'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('restaurants')
          .where('id', isEqualTo: id)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    return ListView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
            new BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              blurRadius: 20.0,
            )
          ]),
          child: new Image.network(snapshot[0].data['picURL']),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
          child: Text(snapshot[0].data['name'],
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 36)),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
          child: Text(snapshot[0].data['desc'],
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 36)),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 500.0,
          width: 500.0,
          child: GoogleMap(
            rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
            scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              controller.addMarker(
                  MarkerOptions(
                    position: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
                  ),
              );
              _controller.complete(controller);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried adding simple_permissions plugin however that plugin seemed to have its own errors so I stopped. The code works well on the emulator however only crashes on my phone.
Thanks

Comment: I am also facing similar problem. Has anyone got solution for this yet?

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error, putting below code in **AndroidManifest.xml** solves the problem.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade your project to AndroidX.

But do not do it manually, use Android Studio as described here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility